# form inside fancybox do not work at all

Tags: jquery, forms, fancybox

I recently switched from simplemodal to fancybox on my website. Everything works great, except for forms. None of the forms inside the fancyboxes work at all. It seems not even the submit button on forms do anything. Also when I click on a file input, the popup asking me which file doesn't come up.

Heres the code for the form:

```
<div id="basic-modal-content">

    <h1>Upload CSV's</h1>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="csvs.php">

    <p>
    <label style="font-size: 8pt;">can:</label>
    <input type="file" name="csv[3]" />
    </p>
    <hr />
    <p>
    <label style="font-size: 8pt;">car:</label>
    <input type="file" name="csv[2]" />
    </p>
    <hr />
    <p>
    <label style="font-size: 8pt;">lis:</label>
    <input type="file" name="csv[5]" />
    </p>
    <hr />
    <p>
    <label style="font-size: 8pt;">veh:</label>
    <input type="file" name="csv[4]" />
    </p>
    <hr />
    <p>
    <label style="font-size: 8pt;">wil:</label>
    <input type="file" name="csv[1]" />
    </p>

    <p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px;">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload CSV's" />
    </p>

    </form>

</div>
```

I show the fancybox by using `$("#basic-modal-content").fancybox().click();` when a button is clicked on the page.

Comment: Use colorbox instead, much more solid plugin and forms do work, got experienced before. http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Comment: im using fancybox because its very adaptive when viewed on mobile devices. colorbox not so much.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking where to buy pizza and everybody starts complaining about pizza and say you should eat burgers instead ;)

Comment: i know. this question is about fancybox. if i wanted to use an alternative, i would. this has to be a simple fix.

Comment: Your form seems to be working fine in fancybox, check **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zMb4p/)** ... it might be something else. It would be easier f you create a test page and share a link.

Comment: JFK that worked awesome! i think it was because i was improperly calling the fancybox to open.